# ORA-01790 with EntityFramework

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, entity-framework, ora-01790

I'm using Entity-Framework with oracle.

I have a table 'Person' 
and a linking table 'Manager' that have 2 columns that are FK to 'Person' table.

(the first column is the manager and the second is the employee, each person has a manager)

of course, the EF did not generated the linking table.

when I'm trying to select a person.Include('Employees') i get a ORA-01790 error
that means 'expression must have same datatype as corresponding expression'

All i want to do is to take a manager and get all of his employees.

I read the solutions online and did not find any answer,

help?!

Answer (score 1):

Very old question to answer, which might be indirectly relevant to your question.

The Entity Framework provider for Oracle is not able to handle more than 2 Include statements on a query.

It generates SQL that Oracle cannot handle  which produces the "ORA-01790: expression must have same datatype as corresponding expression" error.

Some discussion of this issue here:
https://community.oracle.com/thread/2349719

Answer (score 0):

A data type mismatch error in relationship usually means the key data types are incompatible ie. key a is a string and key b is int

I would check your data types to make sure they match

Can you post your code so we can have a better idea of what's causing the error

Comment: both of the keys are of the same table, so there is no way that i have different types

Comment: just because they are the same table does not necessarily mean they the same datatype if column a is a string and column b is a integer then these types are incompatible in a relationship they are not directly comparable unless one is converted to another data type which is not directly supported in entity framework you need to change the data type of one of your columns to create a relationship